# Having trouble DOM parsing

Tags: parsing, dom, attributes, element

I am learning to parse an XML file using DOM however I seem to be stuck at how to enter the deeper nodes in the list.
This is the code I am using:

```
Node n = nlist.item(i); 
     // get ID 
     Element element = (Element)n; 
     String id = element.getAttribute("id"); 
     // create a student object 
     Student st = new Student(id); 
     // get child nodes 
     NodeList slist = n.getChildNodes(); 
     for (int j = 0; j < slist.getLength(); j++) { 
     Node selement = slist.item(j); 
     if (selement.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
         String textval = selement.getTextContent(); 
         if (selement.getNodeName().equals("FirstName")) 
             st.setFirstName(textval); 
         if (selement.getNodeName().equals("LastName")) 
             st.setLastName(textval); 
         if (selement.getNodeName().equals("Address")) 
         {
             NodeList slist2 = n.getChildNodes();
             for(int k = 0; k < slist2.getLength(); k++) {
                 Node selement2 = slist2.item(k);
                    if(selement2.getNodeName().equals("Street"))
```

For an XML file formated like:

```
<Student_Data>
<Student id="11111">
<FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
<LastName>Edwards</LastName>
<Address>
    <Street>345 North</Street>
    <City>Brea</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>99999</Zip>
    <Phone>(714) 444-4444</Phone>
</Address>
<Classes>
    <Class crn="5555">
        <Name>CIS 100</Name>
        <Units>3</Units>
        <Grade>A</Grade>
    </Class>
    <Class crn="7777">
        <Name>CIS 111</Name>
        <Units>4</Units>
        <Grade>B</Grade>        
    </Class>
</Classes>
</Student>
```

My output finds the First and Last names but none of the other information.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in line 19, you have a copy&paste error: you fetch again the child nodes of the element node `n` you start with. Instead of `n.getChildNodes()` it should be `selement.getChildNodes()`.

You may also consider to use the `element.tagName`attribute for testing the name of an alement. See the diagram below for a summary of the DOM2 core.

[image]

Comment: I am getting that getChildren() is undefined for Element

Comment: Sorry, I confused the DOM2 core with the new DOM4 core which provides this `element.children` attribute. Bit these new DOM4 features are only available in JavaScript at present. So, in your case you have to use the methods you have been using (like `node.getChildNodes()`). I'll edit my answer.